# Check above bar as diacritic symbol

Tags: accents

How can I make diactric symbol looks like "check above bar"? In math mode I can make it by `$\check{\bar{\alpha}}$`, but in math-mode is used another font.

Minimal compilable document is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{GFS Bodoni}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Cyrillic]

\begin{document}
$\check{\bar{\alpha}}$
$\check{\bar{\mathrm{\alpha}}}$\\
I need this font:
ᾱ
\end{document}
```

Another case: I need `U+1F51` symbol "ὑ" with bar between "υ" and "spiritus lenis" sign. It isn't solved by math-mod at all.

I find special font for ancient greek language. It contains some necessarily symbols. Here it is: https://apagreekkeys.org/NAUdownload.html. But font is in .ttf format. How I can set it up to TeX program?

I find solution. Using XeLaTex I don't need some additional action. I can use system fonts directly.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "another font". Do you mean it's in math italics?  What about `$\check{\bar{\mathrm{a}}$` ?  If that's not what you mean, can you please post a minimal compilable document showing what you're doing? Is this a regular language accent? If so, you would probably be better of using XeTeX or LuaTeX and an open type font that supports it.

Answer (score 6):

Composite accents are a pain in legacy TeX.

Here's a somewhat decent implementation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\checkbar}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\kern\fontdimen1\font\v{}\cr\noalign{\vskip-1ex}\={#1}\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\checkbar{a}\={a}

\textit{\checkbar{a}\={a}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I try to use it, but check sign is shifted to the right: https://i.ibb.co/zHcj4m7/barcheck.png